# Do you have a phrase for when someone can't accept other offers for a certain amount of time because they've been made a offer by someone first?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Do you have a phrase for when someone can't accept other offers for a certain amount of time because they've been made an offer for their services by someone first? Can I use *under a bid* for it. For example:

> We have a driver available in the area who could haul the cargo, but he is **under a bid** for 10 minutes. If it expires and isn't booked then I could try to book him for you.

Comment: I think I'd ask why the person you are speaking to needs that information. You could just say "We have a driver who may be available in in ten minutes; if they become available, I could try to book them."

Comment: Because in some logistics companies that's a rule. If the driver is offered a load then they cannot consider other loads until 15 minutes. That's about the time needed to find out whether the load was booked for the driver.

Comment: "under a bid" does not exist. He is currently busy. "on a job".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the context correctly, you have to be careful not to skirt the rules.

I think "under bid" is not an established expression, but suggestive of the meaning you might want.  I would prefer the following wording:

> We have a driver available in the area who could haul the cargo;
> **however**, he is **obligated to a bid** for **the next** 10 minutes. If **the bid
> expires and he** isn't booked, then I could try to book him for you.